# What makes Dasgupta's Algebraic Generalism "Algebraic"?

Tags: metaphysics, ontology

Dasgupta refers to his particular form of structuralism as "algebraic generalism." Why, precisely, is it referred to as algebraic?

Comment: See sections 4.1 and 4.2 here, http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/13367/1/GenOSR.pdf, where the distinction between quantifier generalization and algebraic generalization is made. This paper is the very first link that comes up in Google for the search phrase, "Dasgupta's algebraic generalism."

Comment: Thank you! Algebraic generalism is not an elimination of properties/relations, just quantification then? Is it wrong to see algebraic generalism in the same line of thought as neo-logicism?

Comment: Afraid I can't help. I just linked it from a web search.

Comment: It should be better viewed in the line of structuralism since neo-logicism commits to objects while Dasgupta uses PFL to try to revert commitment to term functors and predicate relations (others such as Dewar uses a type of algebraic logic called cylindric algebra to try to achieve same, yet others also use the classic combinatory logic of type theory) in a more nihilistic way... Since PFL syntax mimicks equational algebraic rules it's called algebraic generalism. Monk once showed two non-isomorphic models are isomorphic under cylindrification if they're definitionally elementarily equivalent.

Comment: Neo-logicism mainly has 2 contemporary schools, one should be more accurately termed neo-Fregeanism replacing Frege's infamous unrestricted Basic Law V with more safer axiom(s) such as Hume's principle to try to setup Frege's 2nd order arithmetic FA (really a weaker practical version of ZFC), some such as Weyl noted integers, rational numbers, and real numbers can all be formalized in a very weak subsystem called RCA0 of 2nd order FA, along with complete separable metric spaces and continuous functions between them. Another one is Zalta's 2nd order modal abstract object theory to derive PA...

Comment: Thank you @DoubleKnot. What had me confused is Azzouni's treatment of PFL/feature placing languages as eliminating properties relations, so I wasn't sure if Algebraic Generalism still maintains a commitment to some type of relations. So, at least under Algebraic Generalism, (some) relations, though not quantification, are still treated as real? Is there a way to recover quantification out from Generalism?

Comment: ‘*Every integer has a successor*’ expressed in FOL as '¬∃x(Zx ∧ ¬∃ySyx)' is translated to PFL as 'νρκZνρS', so yes per surface syntax PFL as object language commits to functors and predicate relations and thus arguably cannot escape commitment to object via Quine's recovery to FOL. Antirealist Azzouni's feature placing language (FPL) is his meta-language to talk about PFL and thus he can eliminate relations in his metaphysics via FPL semantics. Similarly in above ref Glick also claims OSR should be a meta-metaphysical position, not a traditional metaphysical position assumed by many...